# How to store multiple requirements with OR and AND?

Tags: java, object-oriented

Well I'm working on a personal project that needs to check if a user has met certain requirements, and they come in a form of

Requirement: [c1 OR c2] AND [d1 OR d2]

Requirement: [c1 AND c2] OR [d1 AND d2]

Requirement: c1 AND any dn(n can be any integer)

I'm just not sure how to store these sorts of requirements, I'm thinking of using another object to hold c1,c2,d1,d2....dn and OR, but that seems like a roundabout way of doing things. Is there a better method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "storing a requirement"? Are you talking about "implementation of a given specification in a programming language" or about "creating a specification"?

Answer (score 6):

Typically, expressions are represented by abstract syntax trees.

```
public interface Expression {};
public class AND implements Expression {
    public Expression lhs;
    public Expression rhs;
}
public class OR implements Expression {
    public Expression lhs;
    public Expression rhs;
}
public class Requirement implements Expression {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for ASTs. Also, take a look at FOPL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) and implementations thereof, because it looks like you also need quantifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for storing and evaluating your requirements. For your first requirement the sequence is basically:

> c1 c2 OR d1 d2 OR AND

As you see you don't need brackets so the storage format is simple. The evaluation is also very easy to implement, you just need a stack object to push parameter values and binary results to the stack, and to pop and evaluate parameters when an operator is met.

Answer (score 1):

[`IOFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html) and its subclasses (for example, [`AndFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AndFileFilter.html), [`NotFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/NotFileFilter.html) and [`OrFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/OrFileFilter.html))
 in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) could be a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Think of [c1 OR c2] AND [d1 OR d2] as a single requirement. Consider c1, c2, d1, d2 as requirements, say sub requirements or atomic requirements. Now they all have one thing in common. They can be checked if they are met. So let's introduce an interface for that:

```
public interface Requirement {
    public boolean isMet();
}
```

Now atomic requirements can be implemented like

```
public class AtomicRequirement implements Requirement {
    private final boolean met;

    public AtomicRequirement(boolean isMet) {
        this.met = isMet;
    }

    public boolean isMet() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can add compound requirements and build upon the Requirement interface.

```
public class AndRequirement implements Requirement {
    private final Requirement r1, r2;

    public AndRequirement(Requirement r1, Requirement r2) {
        this.r1 = r1;
        this.r2 = r2;
    }

    public boolean isMet() {
        return r1.isMet() && r2.isMet();
    }
}
```

Same goes for OR. You can do it with more complex combinators

```
public class AnyOfTheseRequirement implements Requirement {
    private final List<Requirement> anyOfThese;

    public AnyOfTheseRequirement(List<Requirement> anyOfThese) {
        this.anyOfThese = anyOfThese;
    }

    public boolean isMet() {
        for (Requirement r : anyofThese) {
            if (r.isMet()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and of course

```
public class MakseeRequirement implements Requirement {
    private final AndRequirement r;

    public MakseeRequirement(Requirement c1, List<Requirement> dns) {
        AnyOfTheseRequirement d = new AnyOfTheseRequirement(dns);
        this.r = new AndRequirement(c1, d);
    }

    public boolean isMet() {
        return r.isMet();
    }

}
```

This approach is quite extendable but you can trim it down to the three actual types of requirements you got.